# Hide input and label in span with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, label, hide

I have to hide the checkbox and label. I am able to hide the checkbox, but not the label.

```
<span class="SoToolButtonToolbar" style="white-space:nowrap;">
<input id="_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9" name="_ctl0:_ctl0:_Splitter:CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive:_ctl9" checked="checked" onclick="CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchiveArchiveControl.ChangeEntitySetting(this,'mailing');" type="checkbox">
<label for="_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9" class="TextUnselectable">Kampagnen</label>
</span>
```

I can hide the checkbox with:

```
$('_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9').hide();

or

$("_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9").css("display","none")
```

But i am not able to hide the label for.
I already tried the following code without success:

```
$('label[for=_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9]').hide();
```

But i will get an is null TypeError.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to work to me https://jsfiddle.net/1ka1ng2L/. Maybe there is a CSS rule that is overwriting the `hide()` or another jQuery code. We will have to see the code that replicates the problem you have to be sure. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use class for hide both. it is simple just add same class then one code will hide

```
<span class="SoToolButtonToolbar" style="white-space:nowrap;">
<input id="_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9" name="_ctl0:_ctl0:_Splitter:CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive:_ctl9" checked="checked" class="hide-element" onclick="CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchiveArchiveControl.ChangeEntitySetting(this,'mailing');" type="checkbox">
<label for="_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9" class="TextUnselectable hide-element">Kampagnen</label>
</span>
```

then use this code

```
$('.hide-element').hide();
```

or you this code for input filed . you missing #tag for id selector

```
$("#_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9").hide();
```

this is for label

```
$('label[for="_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9"]').hide();
```

Comment: The code OP provided works. How would this change that?

Comment: $('_ctl0__ctl0__Splitter_CustomContactActivityDcoumentArchive__ctl9').hide();

missing # tag

Comment: The problem is not that. Maybe that is just a typo. The OP said that he can't hide the label, not the input.

Comment: so how can understand that typo issue?